# simple instantiations of python classes

Tags: python

Can you please explain why 'hello world' isn't returned below? What do I need to modify for it to be expressed properly when called? Thanks.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     i=12345
...     def f(self):
...         return 'hello world'
...     
>>> x=MyClass()
>>> x.i
12345
>>> x.f
<bound method MyClass.f of <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x060100F8>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When inside the REPL (or the Python console, or whatever) the value returned by the last statement will always be printed. If it is just a value the value will be printed:

```
>>> 1
1
```

If it is an assignment, then nothing will be printed:

```
>>> a = 1
```

But, watch this:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
```

Ok, so in your code above:

```
>>> x=MyClass()
>>> x # I'm adding this :-). The number below may be different, it refers to a
      # position in memory which is occupied by the variable x
<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x060100F8>
```

So, the value of x is an instance of MyClass located at a spot in memory.

```
>>> x.i
12345
```

The value of x.i is 12345, so it will be printed as above.

```
>>> x.f
<bound method MyClass.f of <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x060100F8>>
```

The value of f is a method of x (that's what it means to have `def` in front of something, it is a method). Now, since it is a method, let's call it by adding the `()` after it:

```
>>> x.f()
'hello world'
```

The value returned by f method on the MyClass instance in the variable x is 'hello world'! But wait! There are quotes. Let's get rid of them by using the `print` function:

```
>>> print(x.f()) # this may be print x.f() (note the number of parens)
                 # based on different versions of Python. 
hello world
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @cwallenpoole! That is such a thorough reply. I really appreciate your clear explanation.

Comment: @niper - Incidentally, cwallenpoole's answer is (in my opinion) a much clearer and more thorough answer than mine. Don't feel the need to mark mine right just because I happened to get more votes early on! Mark whichever one helps you the most as "accepted". :)

Comment: Thanks, @Joe Kington. You are a very fair person. I wish this medium would allow for more than one correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

`f` is a method, so you need to call it. i.e. `x.f()`

It's no different than if you define a function without the class:

```
def f():
    return 'something'
```

If you just refer to `f`, you'll get the function itself

```
print f
```

yields `<function f at 0xdcc2a8>`, while

```
print f()
```

yields `"something"`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Joe Kington! I was going through a tutorial and that wasn't mentioned. Thanks again.